# Boost test unresolved external with static variable

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, boost-test

Alright, so I've looked through a number of the questions asked on stack overflow regarding this and haven't been able to find anything that quite answers my issue.

This is the error that I'm getting when linking a boost test project against my production code. I'm using MSVS-2013:

> 2 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static class std::shared_ptr Debug::_Debug" (?_Debug@Debug@@0V?$shared_ptr@VDebug@@@std@@A)    C:\Code\Main.Testing\B.obj
>   3   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   C:\Code\Main.Testing\Debug\Main.Testing.exe

Here is the code causing the error:

Debug.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <memory>
class Debug
{
    private:
    static std::shared_ptr<Debug> _Debug;

    public:
    static std::shared_ptr<Debug> Instance()
    {
        if (!_Debug)
        {
            _Debug.reset(new Debug);
        }

        return _Debug;
    }

    Debug() {}
    ~Debug() {}
    void Exit(std::string sMessage)
    {
        //Do stuff.
        return;
    }
};
```

Debug.cpp:

```
#include "Debug.h"

std::shared_ptr<Debug> Debug::_Debug;
```

Test file B.cpp in a separate test project:

```
#pragma once
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK

#include <boost\test\unit_test.hpp>
#include "<path-to-folder>/Debug.h"

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE(B)

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(testCaseB)
{
    Debug::Instance()->Exit("blah");
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```

The code compiles and the tests run fine when I remove the static variable from the above file. The solution also compiles, links, and runs fine when I exclude the test project but include the static variable so I'm assuming that it's something with my set-up. I've been tinkering with it for a while now and am stumped at what it could be. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: The only problem that I can think of is that `Debug.cpp` is not getting linked together with that "separate test project" in which B.cpp resides.  (I trust you have tried getting rid of `typedef std::shared_ptr<Debug> DebugPtr;` and replacing all references to `DebugPtr` with `std::shared_ptr<Debug>` before asking the question, right?)

Comment: @MikeNakis Yes, this was one of the first things that I tried as I've run into that situation before. It did not change the outcome, though. I'll take out the typedef in my example to avoid that confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure why the testing project wasn't catching the definition of the static variable within the .cpp file but I've found a workaround, although it's kinda hacky.

In my test project, in the file containing the 'main' definition, I added the .cpp file of Debug as an #include(where the static variable is defined). Like so:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK

#ifndef BOOST_TEST_MODULE ProjectTesting
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE ProjectTesting
#endif
#ifndef BOOST_TEST_MAIN
#define BOOST_TEST_MAIN
#endif

#include <boost\test\unit_test.hpp>
#include "<path-to-folder>/Debug.cpp"
```

It's probably not the best solution but it finally compiling and running correctly. If anyone can think of a less hacky workaround then let me know.